# Tezos on a ERC20 Wallet

Tags: smart-contracts, wallets

Sorry in advanced, my english is not the best. but i have to try.

Situation: I bought Tezos on the Binance App. Then i sent all the Tezos to my Wallet (ERC20 Wallet). Now its not showing on the wallet, coz Tezos is not a ERC20 Token.
But if i look on my wallet Adress at bscscan, i can see the tezos inside: https://bscscan.com/address/0xee1a56359f778c2fc3608bc743136b971dad4138#tokentxns

Now my question: are my tezos now completely lost, or you know a possibility to recover them back?

Sorry again for my english.. :-D And thanx in advanced for the help
Greetings from switzerland

Comment: You did not buy tez, you bought an IOU (obligation) from Binance tokenized on their chain which uses an ERC20 standard similar to the one on Ethereum. Contact Binance to ask how you can redeem it for tez, and send it a Tezos wallet such as Kukai or Galleon.

Answer (score 0):

A few things..

Contacting Binance customer support won't help you since they no longer have access to those funds, since you withdrew it to your wallet.

You aren't seeing those tokens on your balance via your wallet interface because they aren't ERC20 tokens. You did not do an ERC20 withdrawal, you did a BEP20 withdrawal.

ERC20 tokens are on the Ethereum network and BEP20s are on BSC (which is an Ethereum Virtual Machine). For example, you can use Metamask to connect to BSC, then you will be able to interact with those tokens.

I'm guessing you have access to that Ethereum address, right? And that you didn't even realize you were sending to the Binance Smart Chain but thought you were sending an ERC20?

I'm not sure which wallet your using but you should be able to access those tokens, one way or another.

After you have connected to BSC via Metamask (or a different app), you will have to send BNB to that address to move your BEP20 XTZ out of that address.

If you want actual XTZ on the Tezos network, send it back to Binance and trade it for real XTZ and withdraw it to an actual Tezos wallet.